# How to create success notification in apache ofbiz

Tags: apache, entity-framework, erp, ofbiz

is there any way to create success notification whenever i create any information via a form in ofbiz.
for example: I want to have success notification when a product is created

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a notification like this, but first you have to ask the user if he wants to allow notifications.

```
Notification.requestPermission(function() {
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        // user approved.
        // use of new Notification(...) syntax will now be successful
        new Notification('Success', { body: 'Success!' });
    } else if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
        // user denied.
    } else { // Notification.permission === 'default'
        // user didn’t make a decision.
        // You can’t send notifications until they grant permission.
    }
});
```

Comment: oh sorry, i thought this question was about javascript